# I am trying to use fetch_assoc() but it gives error undifined method

Tags: php, pdo, magento2

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql::fetch_assoc() in /var/www/html/magento22/mage.php:145

here is my code

```
$data = array();
/* ORDERS */

$result = $write->query('select c.sku, v.value, if(iv.qty = 0 and 
                            (if(iv.use_config_backorders = 1,\'Allow Backorder\',if(iv.backorders = 101,\'Allow pre-order\',\'No Backorder\'))) = \'No Backorder\'
                            , \'disabled\',\'enabled\') as status, iv.qty, 
                            if(iv.use_config_backorders = 1,\'Allow Backorder\',if(iv.backorders = 101,\'Allow pre-order\',\'No Backorder\')) as stock_status,
                            if(e.product_id is null,\'No\',\'Yes\') in_wow,
                            d.value as pre_date
                            from catalog_product_entity c
                            join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on v.entity_id = c.entity_id and v.attribute_id = 71
                            join catalog_product_entity_int s on s.entity_id = c.entity_id and s.attribute_id = 96
                            join cataloginventory_stock_item iv on iv.product_id = c.entity_id
                            join catalog_product_entity_varchar d on d.entity_id = iv.product_id and d.attribute_id = 182
                            left join catalog_category_product e on e.product_id = c.entity_id and category_id = 61
                            join catalog_product_website w on w.product_id = c.entity_id
                            where c.type_id = \'simple\' and w.website_id = 1 and s.value = 1
                        ');

if(is_object($result))
{   
    while ($resultsArray = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if(empty($data))
           $data[] = array_keys($resultsArray);

        $data[] = $resultsArray;
    } var_dump($data);
}
```

there is no connection problem and also my object $result has values. so no problem with that.

Comment: There is no `fetch_assoc()` in PDO itself, you would need `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Not sure about Magento though...

Comment: I have tried it but It is not fetching any value from $result but $result has many values.

Comment: How can I convert magento 1 method fetch_assoc() into magento 2. Main point is this.

Comment: You should try running that query in your DB backend (phpmyadmin) to see what it gives you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing: `while ($resultsArray = $result->fetch_assoc())`

to: `while ($resultsArray = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

or could by `while ($resultsArray = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`